# How to merge make PhotoBooth and face detection to work together?

Tags: javascript, merge, html5-canvas, computer-vision, face-detection

This is probably a really simple solution but I have not been able to figure it out at all, So I'm trying to get PhotoBooth.js and the face detection script seen here [Face Detection JavaScript](https://github.com/orls/ccv-purejs) To work in the same page, I want to detect faces within the PhotoBooth window. I have a working demo of PhotoBooth on jsfiddle here: [JSfiddle PhotoBooth Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fgq7L/54/)

From what I understand given the example code to detect faces with Is that you need to ID the canvas correctly? The example code is

```
var face_detect = require('face_detect'),
Canvas = require('canvas');

// ... initialize a canvas object ...

var result = face_detect.detect_objects({ "canvas" : myCanvas,
  "interval" : 5,
  "min_neighbors" : 1 });

console.log('Found ' + result.length  + ' faces.');

for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++){
  var face =  result[i];
  console.log(face);
}
```

So how would I go about getting this example code to work with the photobooth? 
Any help is greatly appreciated to help a newbie out!